# How to generate mnemonics in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cryptojs, mnemonics, web3-react

I want to generate mnemonics in React Native. I have cloned [this project](https://github.com/markspereira/react-native-web3-boilerplate.git). I imported bip39 but I am getting this error in mobile/simulator. Works fine in debug mode in Chrome browser.

> library Error: Secure random number generation is not supported by this browser

I installed bip39 react native library. But when I use that module app is not opening and gets stuck in the splash screen. I tried to use other libraries like bit core bip39, but every lib has the same problem.

How can I create mnemonics in React Native using the above repository which I cloned React Native web3 boiler plate?

Comment: I have updated the answer here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/61306/how-to-generate-mnemonics-from-randombytes

Answer (score 2):

I generated the memonic using [@medardm/react-native-bip39](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@medardm/react-native-bip39) on React Native project.

Answer (score 0):

Working with web3 in react-native i faced this issue a few. You are probably using the bip39 node.js package. The output you get means that is using a browser library that is not present in react-native(it is probably added as dependency in node). What you should use is bip39 for react native, [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bip39) is a link to it.